# Not able to paginate messages in Firebase Android chat application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, chat

I am building a chat application in android using Firebase. I am using Firebase Realtime Database for storing the messages. For a particular chat, If I am fetching all the messages at once then it is working fine. But the problem arises when there are a lot of messages in that chat. So, I am fetching some messages at once when the user opens the chat. And as the user scrolls up to view the previous messages I am fetching more messages from the database. But doing so I am not able to achieve what I want to. I am getting all the messages again when I am scrolling up. Any help in this would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
private lateinit var messageReference: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var messageReferenceListener: ValueEventListener
val msgKeyList = mutableListOf("")
var msgLimit = 10
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_message)

    recyclerview_user_message.adapter = adapter
    listenForMessages(chatUser.uid)

    recyclerview_user_message.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {

                loadMoreMessages(chatUser.uid)
            }
        }
    })

}

private fun listenForMessages(to_user_uid: String?) {

    messageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("/user-messages/$loggedInUseruid/$to_user_uid")
    val messageQuery = messageReference.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(msgLimit)

    messageReferenceListener = messageQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            adapter.clear()
            for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                val chatMessage = snapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)

                lastMessageKey = chatMessage?.timestamp.toString()
                msgKeyList.add(lastMessageKey)
                msgKeyList.reverse()
                lastMessageKey = msgKeyList.get(/*numbers.size - 1*/0)

                addToRecyclerView(chatMessage)


                // recyclerview_user_message.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
            }
            recyclerview_user_message.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)

        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

    })


    private fun loadMoreMessages(to_user_uid: String?) {
        userReference.removeEventListener(userReferenceListener)
        messageReference.removeEventListener(messageReferenceListener)
        msgLimit += 10
        messageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("/user-messages/$loggedInUseruid/$to_user_uid")
        val messageQuery = messageReference.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(msgLimit)

        messageReferenceListener = messageQuery.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                adapter.clear()
                for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                    val chatMessage = snapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)

                    lastMessageKey = chatMessage?.timestamp.toString()
                    msgKeyList.add(lastMessageKey)
                    msgKeyList.reverse()
                    lastMessageKey = msgKeyList.get(/*numbers.size - 1*/0)

                    addToRecyclerView(chatMessage)

                    // recyclerview_user_message.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
                }
                recyclerview_user_message.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)

            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

        })

    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Alex, Suppose initially if I am fetching 20 messages from the server, then on reaching the end of these 20 messages i want to fetch the previous 10 messages. Bit with the current implementation I am getting 20 messages initially and then on reaching the end I am getting 30 messages from server (20 initial and 10 previous). The expected output is to fetch only the previous 10 messages, not complete 30.